# Nginx (Perl) regular expression to reroute from a URL to another

Tags: regex, perl, nginx

I have a wordpress blog where I have a series of posts with their own slugs. Recently I've noticed legitimate 404 errors where people go to mysite.com/my-slug/&somestuff. or mysite.come/my-slug/somestuff. I've no idea where they got 'somestuff' from but I want to be able to prevent that.

I wrote a regex to reroute from mysite.com/my-slug/anything to mysite.com/my-slug/

```
^/easy-fluffy-american-pancakes/.+
```

That works just fine. Well almost. As it turns out, my print-friendly view of any post is

```
^/easy-fluffy-american-pancakes/print/1234
```

1234 is the post ID. So now, that also gets redirected to the post. How can I exclude print from the redirect?

```
^/easy-fluffy-american-pancakes/(.+)|(?!print/[0-9]*/)
```

I can't quite get it to work. Either it doesn't match or I get too many redirects.

Comment: I think you want the negative lookahead right after the forward slash `^/easy-fluffy-american-pancakes/(?!print/[0-9])(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/LifGRJ/1 If you don't want to match print at all, you can use for example `^/easy-fluffy-american-pancakes/(?!print\b)(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/PehXrT/1

Comment: It sounds like the weird URLs are probably just people trying to exploit your site. I wouldn't reroute them at all. In fact, I'd probably make them return 500s (fake 500s) or leave them as 404. Typically bots won't stop because of this, though, but I don't want to make them think they've found something that will respond.

Comment: Yes I was definitely wondering about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close

```
^/easy-fluffy-american-pancakes/(?!print/[0-9]).+
```

Read `(?!...)` as "not followed by ...". From the perspective of the outside of the `(?!...)`, `(?!...)` doesn't match anything, so the `.+` starts matching immediately after the `/`.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to escape the / character?

Comment: Nevermind... It wasn't working because of caching.

Comment: You might want to make it `(?!print/[0-9]+$).+` so that print URL's with trailing trash will also be redirected.

Comment: @lordadmira That breaks `.../print/1234?o=1`

Comment: @ikegami That's what I was intending.  `/print/1234?o=1` would redirect but `/print/1234` would not.

Comment: @lordadmira, Again, that would be bad. I'm not sure why I have to spell this out for you, but `.../print/1234?...` should go to the same page as `.../print/1234`. In fact, lots of web sites tack on parameters to links (e.g. for tracking purposes), and you would break all those link (in addition to those created by the host site itself).

Comment: @ikegami How can you say it would be bad?  You don't know the use case.  Why do you have a problem with me laying out another option?  As I wrote, if trailing garbage on prints is an issue, here's how you would catch those.  You've got to stop being so imperative and be more subjunctive, like me.  Either way my answer is a valuable illustration of not-matching for anyone else coming here.  I shouldn't have to spell this out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an end of string check to the negative look ahead, it will also catch `print`s with trailing garbage.  If that's an issue.

```perl
print "foo/" =~ m{foo/(?!print/[0-9]+$).+} ? "redirect" : "pass";
pass

print "foo/9ujsdu" =~ m{foo/(?!print/[0-9]+$).+} ? "redirect" : "pass";
redirect

print "foo/print/1234" =~ m{foo/(?!print/[0-9]+$).+} ? "redirect" : "pass";
pass

print "foo/print/1234?o=1" =~ m{foo/(?!print/[0-9]+$).+} ? "redirect" : "pass";
redirect
```

Comment: That would be bad. That would break `.../print/1234?...`, which should go to the same page as `.../print/1234?...`. Why would your default assumption be otherwise? I already pointed this out before you posted this...